# Scala transform list of tuples to a tuple of lists

Tags: scala

How can I transform a list of tuples `List[(A,B)]` to a tuple of lists `(List[A], List[B])`?

I have tried for following but it looks crude and I was hoping there was a better way of doing this

```
  val flat: List[AnyRef] = aAndB.map{ x =>
    x.map(y => List(y._1, y._2))
  }.flatMap(x => x)

  val typeA: List[A] = flat.filter {
    case x: A => true
    case _ => false
  }.map(_.asInstanceOf[A])     

  val typeB: List[B] = flat.filter {
    case x: B => true
    case _ => false
  }.map(_.asInstanceOf[B])
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You want `unzip`

```
scala> List((1,"a"), (3, "b"), (4, "d")).unzip
res1: (List[Int], List[String]) = (List(1, 3, 4),List(a, b, d))
```

Similarly there is an `unzip3` for `List[Tuple3[A, B, C]]`, though anything of higher arity you'd have to implement yourself.

```
scala> List((1,"a", true), (3, "b", false), (4, "d", true)).unzip3
res2: (List[Int], List[String], List[Boolean]) = (List(1, 3, 4),List(a, b, d),List(true, false, true))
```

Comment: For higher arities you could use [product-collections](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections)